# AVButton on a AVPlayerViewController Frame

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avplayerviewcontroller

I need to add a button exactly under the Close Button of the AVPlayer.
So I need to find the exact frame of this button for different screen sizes,

but I can not find the way to access this button.

**Note:** In the "Debug View Hierarchy" the button presented as "**AVButton**".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially there is no Close Button click event access, an engineer from Apple said about it here..https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20979